how can i pass a 4bit quantized model, quantized using bitsandbytes, to vllm?
when I am trying to pass a 4bit quantized opensource model to vllm I am getting below error.
ValidationError: 1 validation error for VLLM __root__ Unknown quantization method: bitsandbytes. Must be one of ['awq', 'gptq', 'squeezellm', 'marlin']. (type=value_error)

'awq', 'gptq', 'squeezellm', 'marlin', these options are not working with model quantized using bitsandbytes. can someone please help here
